# SQL Server - Restore only primary Filegroup but bring the database online

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore, recovery, filegroups

I'm trying to find out if it's possible to bring a SQL Server 2016 Enterprise database online by restoring only the primary Filegroup. My scenario is, we have a fairly large OLTP database, of around 2TB. About 25% of that size is a single 'history' table, which as the name suggests, just tracks activity.

Each day, this database (in full recovery mode) is backed up and restored to several other environments where it is used for various, typically none-critical purposes. This restore process is slow due to the database size, and the 'history' table is obviously a significant contributer.

Although this 'history' table needs to exist in these other environments (it is referenced by numerous stored procedures), it doesn't need to contain any data. We just need it to exist but it could be blank, or ideally, just contain a few thousand of the most recent rows (not essential).

My first thought in achieving this was to:

1. Move the 'history' table to a secondary filegroup (the database has a single, primary filegroup currently)
2. Perform a backup of only the primary filegroup (this would probably be an extra 'copy_only' backup).
3. Restore this backup to the other environments.

The problem is, after step 3, I can bring the database online, however, I obviously can't reference the 'history' table, since it belongs to an FG that hasn't been restored. If I do, I get an error as expected:

*The query processor is unable to produce a plan for the table or view 'History' because the table resides in a filegroup that is not online.*

So my questions are:

1. Is what I'm trying to achieve even possible using this (or a similar) approach?
2. After step 3, is there a way by which I could 'drop' the secondary filegroup and recreate a blank copy of the 'history' table in the primary filegroup? This would allow the application/stored procedures that rely on its presence (but not it's data) to function. This doesn't appear possible without restoring the secondary filegroup first.
3. Is there just a flat-out better approach that I've not considered?

Note - The 'history' table is not referenced by any FKs, so there are no data integrity issues caused by not having the data there.

I'm aware that there are alternative ways of 'synchronising' multiple databases rather than a backup/restore (replication being one). Unfortunately, that is somewhat out of my control so for now, I'd like to focus on the backup/restore approach. Of course, I'm happy to hear suggestions.

UPDATE - Just to be clear, the rest of the data in the database is needed in each environment, but minus the 'history' table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since J.D. has already given you some good advice on what could be the alternatives, I'm gonna just add how you could achieve specifically what you asked and if you still think it's a good approach for your problem, you can use it.

Here's a database with two filegroups for this example:

```
USE [master]
GO

CREATE DATABASE [Lab]
 ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'Lab', FILENAME = N'C:\Databases\Lab.mdf'), 
 FILEGROUP [HISTORY] 
( NAME = N'Lab_History', FILENAME = N'C:\Databases\Lab_History.ndf')
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'Lab_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Databases\Lab_log.ldf')
 WITH CATALOG_COLLATION = DATABASE_DEFAULT
GO
```

Now we create two tables on that database (each residing on a different filegroup):

```
CREATE TABLE Users (ID int, UserName varchar(50))
ON [PRIMARY];

CREATE TABLE History (ID int, UserName varchar(50))
ON [HISTORY]; --Table History resides on a different Filegroup
```

After that, we backup the filegroup we want to restore later:

```
--Take a COPY_ONLY backup of the PRIMARY Filegroup
BACKUP DATABASE Lab
FILEGROUP = 'PRIMARY'
TO DISK = 'C:\BackupSQL\Lab_PRIMARY.bak'
WITH COPY_ONLY;
```

You can drop the Lab database and restore only the filegroup with our `Users` table:

```
--Restore the Filegroup Backup
RESTORE DATABASE Lab
FILEGROUP = 'PRIMARY'
FROM DISK = 'C:\BackupSQL\Lab_PRIMARY.bak';
```

Finally, the trick to have an empty `History` table online:

```
--Rename the original table
USE Lab;
EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.History', 'History_';

--Recreate an empty History table
CREATE TABLE History (ID int, UserName varchar(50))
ON [PRIMARY]; --Recreates a History table now on the PRIMARY Filegroup
```

Comment: That's brilliantly simple! Quick follow up question - in this method, the database is 'aware' of the secondary filegroup, it just isn't online. Are you aware of any side-effects to this?

Comment: @FrugalShaun I couldn't find any side-effect on the [RESTORE Statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) doc. The only thing I could see on the doc related to performance after after a restore was: *Restoring a database clears the plan cache for the database being restored. Clearing the plan cache causes a recompilation of all subsequent execution plans and can cause a sudden, temporary decrease in query performance.*

Comment: One side-effect that came to my mind now is that if that filegroup is marked as the default on the database. You should change it on the restored database or new objects that users try to create without specifying a different filegroup would not work with the error of a filegroup not available.

Comment: OK good point I'll bear the in mind.

Answer (score 2):

I know you mentioned it's a little bit out of your control, but if you don't need the data at all and just the schema itself, doing a **backup and restore** on a 2 TB database is going to be the least efficient way to accomplish your goal, by far, among probably 10 different options. (You should familiarize yourself with the alternatives and bring this to the attention of whoever's control it is in.)

Some of those alternative options are **Replication** (as you mentioned), **SSIS**, **SQL Agent Job** that keeps the other instances up to date, scripting out the database, or using a [**DACPAC**](https://sqlplayer.net/2018/10/how-to-create-dacpac-file) to deploy just the schema, which would be my choice for you as it's the simplest / makes the most sense. (Also if your limitation in using a different features is because you're not allowed to *setup* anything on the server, **DACPAC** is an already enabled feature, and the process is simpler than **backups** since you just use **SSMS** to generate the file for you, similar to if you were generating scripts. No need to *install* or *setup* anything.)

If your schema doesn't change often, you can even dedicate one empty copy of the database as your "model" which always remains data-less and can easily be used to generate new databases off of (even if you still stick to the **backup and restore** methodology, since it'll be a tiny database). Or even if it does change often, you can still do the **backup and restore** to just this one model database, and then truncate the data or use a **DACPAC** there to generate the other instances so that way you don't need to wait on a 2 TB restore more than once.

Comment: Hi. Sorry I probably wasn't clear. I absolutely need the data in the database, I just don't need the data for that one table, which happens to be the biggest, because it's basically just an auditing table that tracks activity. The purpose of the backup/restore is to get that data into other environments to have realistic data for application testing. 

To explain further, if we used replication, we'd basically be replicating the entire database, minus the audit table. It's not unfeasible, but I'd have concerns over the network I/O during peak times.

Comment: @FrugalShaun Gotcha, that's a different story then. Size of database <> I/O bandwidth, so without knowing how *active* your database is, e.g. how many transactions for how much data per X,Y,Z (second, minute, hour, etc) it's hard to say if that should be a real concern. Though I've worked with both multi-TB databases in a fairly high transactional environment (for Financial Tech.) and with **Replication**, and I've never encountered that being a bottleneck. The network bandwidth use is only between the SQL Servers involved in the **Replication** stack so it definitely doesn't impact end users.

Comment: @FrugalShaun Anyway, I'll think of what you can do, given my new understanding of your situation. My current recommendation would be to keep your `history` table in it's own database to decouple it from the main functions of your database and then even the **backup and restore** methodology would be cleaner / faster. But I understand that's probably not the most easily accomplishable solution since it'll likely involve code changes.

Comment: Also knowing how many environments you currently have to restore the database to (on average), what kind of purposes it undergoes in those other environments (for example, is it all for reporting purposes?), and why those other purposes can't be ran on a single copy of the database, would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks. You’re correct regarding the code changes. Although off the top of my head, a synonym may help there which I’m going to look into. The DB is highly transactional but even so, replication is an option so I’ll give that more thought. I’m also going to look into page/row compression as a means of making the History table smaller in the first place, although it’s largely varchar(max) column, which I don’t believe compress down.

Comment: @FrugalShaun Compression isn't a bad idea to look into even with it being a majority of `VARCHAR(MAX)` fields. Any compression here will be better than none. You may find this system procedure [sp_estimate_data_compression_savings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-estimate-data-compression-savings-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) of use since it can tell you a rough estimate of what different types of compression will save you, for different indexes or at the whole table level.

Comment: Regarding the other environments, I'm not sure what they're all used to be honest but believe it's primarily testing by different teams. Different environments may also be different stages of the software release process and therefore have some minor schema differences (that are re-applied after the restore). It's not great and long been a source of frustration, but it is what it is for the short term at least!

Comment: Just to follow up. The synonym solution I mentioned seems to work well. So I can move the history table to its own database (as per your suggestion), drop it from the source database and replace it with a synonym that points to the new table. This appears to work seamlessly.

Comment: @FrugalShaun Funny you mentioned that, as **synonyms** aren't very popular in SQL Server but as of lately I find myself using them more and more, generally for migrations as in your case. Wish I thought of it earlier, but my brain was still waking up lol. Glad it's working for you!